# Where can I get Imposter Ditto?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Ditto's Hidden Ability is Imposter.

Where can a Ditto with Imposter be legitimately acquired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Hidden Grotto that's in the Giant Chasm, in the forest. It's rare to find, though, as far as I know.